# VueJS meaning of following operator '!!'

Tags: vue.js

Following tutorials in VueJS and I often come across the following:

```
hasFooterSlot () {
  return !!this.$slots['footer']
}
```

isn't this the same as:

```
hasFooterSlot () {
  return this.$slots['footer']
}
```

What is the purpose of using the `!!` operator?

Comment: It's a standard JS idiom. It converts to a boolean. Whether it is necessary would depend on how the value is used.

Comment: There is a convention that methods starting `is` or `has` should return booleans. Typically it doesn't really matter and a truthy/falsey value would be just as good. One advantage of using a proper boolean is that it stops it being misused. e.g. Someone might try to call `hasFooterSlot` as a way to access the contents of the slot. The type conversion prevents that misuse.